# std::lower_bound and comparator function with different types?

Tags: c++, stl

I have an array of structures, sorted on a member of a structure, something like:

```
struct foo
{
    int bar;
    double baz;
};

// An array of foo, sorted on .bar
foo foos[] = { ........ };
// foos[0] = {0, 0.245}
// foos[1] = {1, -943.2}
// foos[2] = {2, 304.222}
// etc...
```

I want to find the element with a specific `.bar` value. It might or might not be in the array, and I'd like to do it in O(log(n)) time, since the array is sorted.

`std::lower_bound` is what I'd normally go for, but I need to specify a comparison function. However, the type of the members of the array (`struct foo`) and the searched value (`int`) are not the same, thus, my comparator is:

```
bool comp(foo a, int b)
{
    // ...
}
// --- or ---
bool comp(int a, foo b)
{
    // ...
}
```

It looks like the first will work with `gcc`, but I was wondering if the order of the arguments to the comparison function was specified by the standard, or if I'm relying on compiler behavior.

I'd like to avoid constructing a `foo` to pass to `std::lower_bound` here, as a full `foo` isn't required, and could be costly. My other option would be to wrap the `foo *` in a custom iterator that only exposed the .bar member.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the standard, 25.3.3.1/3, on `std::lower_bound()`:

> **Returns**: The furthermost iterator `i` in the range `[first, last]` such
>   that for any iterator `j` in the range
>   `[first, i)` the following
>   corresponding conditions hold: `*j <
>   value` or `comp(*j, value) != false`.

From that, you may use

```
bool comp(foo a, int b)
```

or you may compare two `foo` instances and then access `bar` in both of them.

Comment: I'm just confirming wilhelmtell's answer.  This wasn't true in C++98 but after a long hard-fought battle, became true in C++03: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#270 .  Note that if you use upper_bound, you need the reverse order of arguments.  And if you use equal_range, you will need both orders.

Answer (score 3):

This should really be a comment to wilhelmtell's post, but I don't have enough points to do that yet...

I just wanted to point out that this also works for the MS compiler, but you'll need to define

```
comp(foo lhs, foo rhs)
```

otherwise your code won't compile in debug mode.