# Using lower_bound, upper_bound, and binary_search to find the object with an equal member field

Tags: c++, search, stl

I have a struct that looks like this,

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
};
```

I have a vector of these structs that look like this,

```
vector<Foo> foos;
```

All of the `Foo`s are sorted by the integer `a` in ascending order using the STL sort() function. Now I want to get the `Foo` object that has the member field `a` less than or equal to a given number, like the STL lower_bound() function. The problem is that the STL lower_bound function declaration looks like this:

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T, class Compare>
  ForwardIterator lower_bound ( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
                                const T& value, Compare comp );
```

So while I want to do something like,

```
lower_bound(foos.begin(), foos.end(), 5, custom_comp);
```

I can't because the int I'm looking for (5 in this case) is not of the type `Foo`. I'm having this issue with lower_bound(), upper_bound(), and binary_search(). custom_comp only defines the ordering and doesn't define that an object with a = 5 actually equals the int 5.

Is there any elegant way of doing this with STL?

Edit:

I realized my example doesn't completely represent my problem. What I actually have is that Foo contains two ints, a and b. When I call lower_bound, I don't have access to b (because I don't care about it). Now the issue with billz answer is that I'd have to define a constructor that takes only `a` as a parameter, which isn't very elegant in my opinion (because b is left undefined or abitrary, and this constructor can be used anywhere in the code). But if this is the only option, I'll take it.

Comment: There is a better solution in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072257/stdlower-bound-and-comparator-function-with-different-types], and this question is a possible duplicate of that question.    Summary: In the lower_bound template, class T does not have to be the data type of the container  content ranged by the two iterator [first, last).   That means, T can be just an integer to be compared.  You can just write the comparator to be  `bool Compare(Foo & f, int value) { return f.a < value; }`.  And it is working since C++03.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide a constructor to your struct Foo

```
struct Foo {
  Foo(int x):a(x){
  }
    int a;
};
```

you can now call:

```
std::lower_bound(foos.begin(), foos.end(), 5, custom_comp);
```

or

```
std::lower_bound(foos.begin(), foos.end(), Foo(5), custom_comp);
```

or

```
Foo f(5);
std::lower_bound(foos.begin(), foos.end(), f, custom_comp);
```

The suggested way is:

```
struct Foo {
  explicit Foo(int x):a(x){
  }
    int a;
};

std::lower_bound(foos.begin(), foos.end(), Foo(5), custom_comp);
```

Comment: Would I then have to define a operator== for Foo?

Comment: @gsingh2011 no, an `operator<`, but only if you don't use `custom_comp` which does the same thing.

Comment: sometimes implicit conversion is painful

Comment: Problem 1: `Foo` with only an `int` state may not be a valid `Foo`.  Problem 2: `Foo` could be expensive to make.  Problem 3: You are hacking the data structure so you can run some algorithm on the data structure that doesn't require any hacking on the data structure.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont objections are valid. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5072289/213871) answer provides a better solution

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you can use the following:

```
std::lower_bound(foos.begin(), foos.end(), Foo{5},
    [](const Foo& f1, const Foo& f2) { return f1.a < f2.a; });
```

Or in C++03:

```
Foo f = {5};
std::lower_bound(foos.begin(), foos.end(), f, custom_comp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your custom_comp accept both `foo` and `int` as arguments.  This means it either needs to be a functor, or it could take `foo_sort_helper` arguments (which can be constructed from an `int` or a `foo`) and order those.

Or, to be explicit:

```
struct FooSortHelper
{
  int ordering;
  FooSortHelper( Foo const& foo ):ordering(foo.value) {}
  FooSortHelper( int i ): ordering(i) {}
  FooSortHelper( FooSortHelper const& other):ordering(other.ordering) {}
  bool operator<( FooSortHelper const& other ) { return ordering < other.ordering }
};

auto lower = std::lower_bound( vec.begin(), vec.end(), 5,
  []( FooSortHelper left, FooSortHelper right ) {
    return left < right;
  }
);
```

You see how I encapsulate how `Foo` is sorted in the `FooSortHelper`?  And by allowing it to be constructed from an int, I allow `Foo` to be compared against `int` seemlessly.

The alternative I mentioned is to create a class with operator() overloaded on each pair of `Foo` and `int` (all 4 of them).  I find the above easier.

If the type(s) you are sorting on is expensive to copy (such as `std::string`) the `FooSortHelper` can store a reference to said fields.

Comment: But lower_bound would try passing Foo to custom_comp... It wouldn't know to pass the int inside Foo.

Comment: Exactly.  So `custom_comp` takes both `Foo`s and `int`s.  This requires either a functor `struct custom_comp { bool operator()(int, Foo const&) const; bool operator()(Foo const&, int) const; bool operator()(int, int) const; bool operator()(Foo const&, Foo const&) const; };`, which I find tiresome, or the above helper trick.  The helper can be constructed by either a `Foo` or an `int` and stores only the parts of the `Foo` that are required for sorting.  I did it with a lambda, but you could use a `custom_comp` function or functor if you prefer.