# C++ std::lower_bound() function to find insertion point for an index-sorted vector

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, binary-search, c++03

Suppose I have `vector<Foo>`, and its index is externally sorted in a `vector<int>` by a key field `.bar` in class `Foo`.   e.g.

```
class Foo {
public:
     int bar;
     int other;
     float f;
     Foo(int _b, int _o, float _f): bar(_b), other(_o), f(_f) {}
};

vector<Foo> foos;
vector<int> sortedIndex;
```

`sortedIndex` contain the sorted indices of `foos`.

Now, I want to insert something to `foos`, and keep it sorted externally (sorting key is `.bar`) in `sortedIndex`.  e.g.

```
foos.push_back(Foo(10,20,30.0));
sortedIndex.insert(
                   lower_bound(sortedIndex.begin(),
                               sortedIndex.end(),
                               10 /* this 10 won't work*/,
                               some_compare_function
                   ),
                   1,
                   foos.size()-1
);
```

Apparently, the number 10 won't work: The vector `sortedIndex` contains indices, not value, `some_compare_function` will be confused, as it does not know when to use direct value, and when to transform the index to value (`foo[i].bar` rather than just `i`) before comparison.

Any idea?  I have seen the answer to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072257/stdlower-bound-and-comparator-function-with-different-types).  The answer suggests that I can use compare function `bool comp(foo a, int b)`.  However, how can the binary search algorithm know that the `int b` refers to `.bar` not `.other`, since both are defined as `int`?

I would like also to know if the answer will be different for C++03 and C++11. Please mark your answer C++03/C++11.  Thanks.

Comment: Why will `some_compare_function` be confused? Its first parameter is always an index to look up in `foos`, and the second parameter is a value of `bar`.

Comment: So, if `Foo` defines `.other` before `.bar`, then `.other` will be used as the key?  In real example, my `bar` is buried deep in `Foo`...

Comment: It doesn't matter where `.bar` is located. The comparison function should take it from wherever it is, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`some_compare_function` won't be "confused". Its first parameter is always an element of `sortedIndex`, and the second parameter is a value to compare to, that is `10` in your example. So in C++11 you can implement it like this:

```
sortedIndex.insert(
    lower_bound(sortedIndex.begin(),
        sortedIndex.end(),
        10,
        [&foos](int idx, int bar) {
            return foos[idx].bar < bar;
        }
    ),
    foos.size()-1
);
```

Comment: Do you mean, in general, that the type of the 3rd parameter in `lower_bound()`, should agree with the 2nd parameter in the compare function, so that we can write compare function in different type than the sorted vector?  And the `upper_bound()` seems to use 1st parameter in the compare function for the 'different type parameter', right?

Comment: @RobinHsu yes, exactly, except "so that we can write compare function in different type than the sorted vector" - I didn't quite understand that.

Comment: Thanks.  In C++03, I only have to use normal function to replace the lambda function in your example.  My compiler supports only C++03 though..

Comment: For "so that we can write compare ..."  =>  Never mind, just ignore it.   I was stereotyped by the compare function concept in sorting algorithms, where the compare function should have the same type for both arguments.

Comment: An additional question:  I am using C++03, and thus no lambda functions.  It won't even have std::bind()  (>= C++11 only), and I do not want to use 3rd party library such as `boost` unless necessary.  Is there any way to bind `foos` in a compare function?  I am thinking of `std::bind1st` and `std::bind2nd`, but seems not suitable...