# Is there a Function to move an element in a vector to a new Position inside the same vector

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector, insert

I have a Sorted vector of strings and whenever a new string is added we have a function which will allow us to calculate the new position. I should be able to use this position and update the vector.

Example:

- Input `Vector v1{Acr,Adr,Apr,Arr,Asr};`
- Input New String : `Aar`

As soon as the String uis Added  the Vector Becomes
`v1{Acr,Adr,Apr,Arr,Asr,Aar};`

After Addition new position is computed with a Function that Will Return position to insert I1 in this case).

So after Some operation it should become `v1{Aar,Acr,Adr,Apr,Arr,Asr};`

Comment: Are you trying to keep the vector sorted? You may want `std::set` instead. `std::vector::insert` can be used to insert elements at any position, it shifts all following elements down one position to make room for the new element.

Comment: Why add the new element at the end and then moving it, rather than inserting it to the correct position right away?

Comment: [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) can be used to find insertion position.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to insert into an `std::vector`?

How about using [`std::vector::insert`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) then?

Example:

```
v1.insert(v1.begin() + index, new_value);
```

As @Jarod42 commented, you could use [`std::lower_bound`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) to find the insertion position, like this: [C++ std::lower_bound() function to find insertion point for an index-sorted vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207824/c-stdlower-bound-function-to-find-insertion-point-for-an-index-sorted-vect).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a combination of `std::vector::insert` and `std::lower_bound` should be a good match:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using std::vector;
    using std::string;
    using std::lower_bound;
    using std::cout;
    vector<string> v1{"Acr","Adr","Apr","Arr","Asr"};
    auto insertionPoint{lower_bound(begin(v1), end(v1), "Aar")};
    v1.insert(insertionPoint, "Aar");
    for (auto&&s:v1) cout << s << " ";
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h1hPqjEde)

The key element is: `v1.insert(insertionPoint, "Aar");` to insert directly in the right place. If you don't want to use `lower_bound` because you already have the index (let's call it `pos` for the sake of this example), you can always do sth like this `v1.insert(begin(v1)+pos, "Aar");`

And if you really need to append at the end initially (for whatever reason) using `std::sort` sounds like the most natural solution. Although the most inefficient (given you can modify the vector anyway).

Expanding the answer with custom comparison function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
class Sth
{
    std::string name_;
public:
    explicit Sth(const std::string& s) : name_(s) {}
    const std::string& name() const {return name_;}
};


int main(int, char*[])
{
    using std::vector;
    using std::string;
    using std::lower_bound;
    using std::cout;
    vector<Sth> v1{Sth("Acr"),Sth("Adr"),Sth("Apr"),Sth("Arr"),Sth("Asr")};
    auto insertionPoint{lower_bound(begin(v1), end(v1), Sth("Aar"),
        [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs){return lhs.name() < rhs.name();})};
    v1.insert(insertionPoint, Sth("Aar"));
    for (auto&&s:v1) cout << s.name() << " ";
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hEYvMrfPK)

Comment: This Looks good But , my vector doesn't directly contain strings. It is of type class A which contains a Method to get Name and this has to be sorted.4

Comment: @AdityaRamMangalampalli custom comparator can be passed to `lower_bound`, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you mean something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = { "Acr", "Adr", "Apr", "Arr", "Asr" };
    v.push_back( "Aar" );
    
    auto pos = std::upper_bound( std::begin( v ), std::prev( std::end( v ) ),
               v.back() );
               
    if ( pos != std::prev( std::end( v ) ) )
    {
        auto s = std::move( v.back() );
        v.pop_back();
        v.insert( pos, s );
    }
    
    for ( const auto &s : v )
    {
        std::cout << s << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Aar Acr Adr Apr Arr Asr
```